# Pandas New Variable Based On Multiple Conditions

Tags: pandas

I have spent two days searching, any help would be appreciated.

Trying to create c_flg based on values in other columns.

```
a_flg    b_flg    Count    c_flg (Expected Output)
False    True       3      False
True     False      2      False
False    False      4      True
```

a_flg & b_flg are strs, Count is an int

Approaching from two angles, neither successful.

**Method 1:**

```
df['c_flg'] = np.where((df[(df['a_flg'] == 'False') & 
(df['b_flg'] == 'False') &
(df['Count'] <= 6 )]), 'True', 'False')
```

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

**Method 2:**

```
def test_func(df):
    if (('a_flg' == 'False') & 
    ('b_flg' == 'False') &

    ('Count' <= 6 )):
        return True

    else:
       return False


df['c_flg']=df.apply(test_func, axis=1)


TypeError: ('unorderable types: str() <= int()', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Very new to the Python language, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem properly then you need this,

```
df['c_flg']=(df['a_flg']=='False')&(df['b_flg']=='False')&(df['Count']<=6)
df['c_flg']=(df['a_flg']==False)&(df['b_flg']==False)&(df['Count']<=6)#use this if 'x_flg' is boolean
```

Output:

```
   a_flg  b_flg  Count  c_flg
0  False   True      3  False
1   True  False      2  False
2  False  False      4   True
```

Note: For this problem you really don't need `numpy`, pandas itself can solve this without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `np.where` is not necessary, use `~` for invert boolean mask and chain `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
print (df.dtypes)
a_flg     bool
b_flg     bool
Count    int64
dtype: object

df['c_flg'] = ~df['a_flg'] & ~df['b_flg'] & (df['Count'] <= 6)
print (df)
   a_flg  b_flg  Count  c_flg
0  False   True      3  False
1   True  False      2  False
2  False  False      4   True
```

Comment: @MrDecker - You are welcome! So another solution working better for you? `df['c_flg']=(df['a_flg']==False)&(df['b_flg']==False)&(df['Count']<=6)` ?